# Cypress not recognizing my imported module from outside /cypress directory

Tags: javascript, nuxt.js, integration-testing, cypress

I am trying to import a module from a file outside my /cypress directory into the /cypress/integration directory's test.spec.js file like so:

```
import { LAB_MODEL } from '../../models/search/lab-model';
```

But inside this imported module "LAB_MODEL" there are other files being imported using the "@@" at the start of the file imports like

```
import ExperimentDetails from "@@/components/experiment/ExperimentDetails";
```

and I think this is why Cypress isn't working and giving me this error:

```
Error: Webpack Compilation Error
./models/search/lab-model.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@@/components/experiment/ExperimentDetails' in '/Users/hidden/models/search'
resolve '@@/components/experiment/ExperimentDetails' in '/Users/hidden/models/search'
  Parsed request is a module
  using description file: /Users/hidden/package.json (relative path: ./models/search)
    Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
    resolve as module
```

So I think this is the reason why my test won't run, but I have no idea how to make Cypress recognize "@@" imports and can't find any documentation/stackoverflow answers, any help is appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`@@/` looks like something that gets translated into a full path during the Nuxt build.
(ref [The alias Property](https://nuxtjs.org/docs/2.x/configuration-glossary/configuration-alias/)).

Cypress has a separate build that doesn't know about this Nuxt feature. You could try to replicate it with some webpack config via a [preprocessor](https://docs.cypress.io/api/plugins/preprocessors-api), but another way is to have your Nuxt app put a reference to `lab_model` on the window object

```
// somewhere in the Nuxt app
if (window.Cypress) {
  window.lab_model = LAB_MODEL;
}
```

then at the top of the test

```
const lab_model = cy.state('window').lab_model;
```

This has the benefit of giving you the exact same instance of `lab_model`, in case you wanted to stub something.

---

In a starter Nuxt app, I added the code `window.lab_model = LAB_MODEL` in `/pages/index.vue`, but you can add it in any component that imports it, right after the import statement.

In the spec add a `.should()` to test the property exists, to allow the app time to settle.

```js
it('gets labModel from the Nuxt app', () => {

  cy.visit('http://localhost:3000/')

  cy.window()
    .should('have.property', 'lab_model')  // retries until property appears
    .then(labModel => {

      console.log(labModel)

      // test with labModel here
    })
})
```

Comment: This is an elegant answer, but I can't seem to get it to work, there's no obvious spot in my Nuxt app to load that into my window, everywhere I tried I was always met with the error that Cypress can't recognize "cy.state('window').lab_model", and the docs you linked to are a bit vague and don't seem to provide a clear path to my module being recognized

Comment: Nuxt seems to be a bit laggy (at least in dev mode), I can't put my finger on why but adding a `.should()` can fix that